# Is there a way for cygwin to access a Linux (ext3) partition?

Tags: windows, linux, cygwin, ext3

I'd like to be able to access a Linux partition through cygwin on Windows.  My purpose is to backup data from a Linux server to my home computer running Windows 7.  Right now it mostly works, except when there's files with invalid characters or if there are multiple files with the same letters but different case.

Comment: How are you accessing the partition? Via a samba server on the Linux box?

Comment: I'm essentially trying to back-up a Linux server that I'm accessing via SSH, to my Windows computer with an ext3 drive.  Currently I'm just using rsync with cygwin, but then the issues above happen.

Comment: Please show some examples of invalid characters. Cygwin 1.7 has special handling of characters such as `:` that aren't allowed in Windows filenames, mapping them to the "Unicode private use area". Are you using an older Cygwin version?

Comment: The backslash character, namely, which doesn't get re-mapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is use a VirtualBox. This can be done in two ways,

1. Store your data in VMDK files

   - this is pretty simple and safe; you can also keep different sized VMDK files for your backups
2. Create a [RAW disk](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk) access to a actual EXT3 partition on your HDD

   - be warned that this is a tricky way and you can easily break your ext3 partition
     (particularly if you use suspend or hibernate while it is mounted)
   - and, don't try to mount your Windows boot partition RAW in write-mode, ever.

Update:
If you get interested in automation: [VBoxManage](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) lets you control the VM from command line.

Comment: I don't think the potential for damage to the ext3 filesystem is particularly great if you remember to mount it read-only.

Comment: @Eroen, mounting the local partition read-only defeats the purpose of making it a backup target.

Comment: As I understand it, OP wants to extract data from the ext3 filesystem. That might very well be an incorrect assumption, though.

Comment: IMO, OP wants to backup data from Linux Server to his local Windows system and is troubled by the windows-file-name limitations.

Comment: That's a valid stance, and makes more sense. Sorry about the noise.

Comment: No trouble, in fact that gives the OP a chance to clarify. And, for the record it the RAW is read-only mounted afaik there are no corruption risks at all.

Comment: VirtualBox isn't a horrible solution, especially since I already have it setup and whatnot.  But having it constantly running to be able to do the automated back-ups seems pretty heavy duty.  Though, I guess having a whole separate machine would be even more overkill.  Hmmm.  Anyway, this is a valid workaround, but I don't really think this is an exact answer, as you're basically asking me to emulate an entire computer just to get access to a partition ;).

Comment: I see your point and have thought so before. But, with current hardware abilities, running a VBox is not that costly. And, do you really backup that often?

Comment: Nightly.  It's a volatile site with thousands of users accessing it, uploading files all the time.

Comment: Well, then I hope you can get around automating the process unless you find another way to get it done on the Windows machine.

Comment: Alternate thought: can you setup an FTP server or some such on your local machine and make the server 'upload' your backup?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to make a backup by copying a complete directory tree to a different computer, file by file. This is admittedly one way of making a backup, but I would suggest a different approach, especially since it appears to work out badly in your case.

What I do myself (in principle), it to create tarballs of the files I want to back up locally on the Linux server and save them somewhere else through ssh (actually by sshfs, but no matter). This should eliminate problems with filenames as long as the tar implementation on the Linux server handles them.

You could do this by setting up cygwin with an ssh server for the Linux server to connect to, or with a command like

```
ssh $server "tar c -C /var/important ./" > backup.tar
```

run from cygwin on the computer you want to keep the backup on. You could also save the tarballs on the Linux server and transfer them afterwards.

If you want to reduce the amount of bandwidth and diskspace comsumed, I suggest using [star](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/old/private/star.html) in stead of gnu tar, and it's incremental mode, which lets you only include files modified after the previous backup. It will still not do the delta transfer of rsync, and several versions of files will take up disk space, though. On the other hand, a tarball is far simpler to compress efficiently (with xz or something) than a directory tree.

Comment: This is not an option, the data is 25 GB and spans 47,000 files.  It would take forever if I didn't use rsync or something like it.  Even using incremental mode, it'd still be a procedure that simply would take far too much time, and half the amount of space on my server.

Answer (score 0):

There's a registry setting determining whether the Windows kernel treats filenames as case-insensitive:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\obcaseinsensitive
```

Set that to `0` and reboot to allow files differing only in case. See also http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html#pathnames-casesensitive.

Cygwin 1.7 automatically maps characters such as `:` that aren't allowed in Windows filenames into the "Unicode private use area". The one big exception to this is the backslash, which it treats as a directory separator for the sake of Windows interoperability, so the only thing you can do about those is avoid them in Linux filenames, or of course use a different approach altogether.

Comment: This doesn't solve special characters, and this would be quite dangerous in other respects.